# Why might a table scan have a huge I/O Cost?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that table scans are bad, and that every table should have a primary key and clustered index, but I'm wondering what might cause the spectacularly bad performance that I'm seeing below in SQL Server 2008 R2.

For testing's sake, I am doing a `SELECT * FROM myTable` on a table/heap with 1960 rows.  The table has the following columns: (int, datetime, int, int, float, smallint, uniqueidentifier). There are no indexes.  This table has had a long history of inserts and deletes.

I get the following stats from the table scan in the query plan:

```
<RelOp 
  AvgRowSize="57" 
  EstimateCPU="0.002313" 
  EstimateIO="74.4157" 
  EstimateRebinds="0" 
  EstimateRewinds="0" 
  EstimateRows="1960" 
  LogicalOp="Table Scan" 
  NodeId="0" 
  Parallel="false" 
  PhysicalOp="Table Scan" 
  EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="74.418"
  TableCardinality="1960">
```

And from `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`:

`Table 'myTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 100458, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.`

What factors could lead to such a small number of small rows requiring such a massive number of reads (and have the query plan predict the same)?

Comment: Ghosted Records. See [SQL Server “empty table” is slow after deleting all (12 million) records](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14619/708)

Comment: ^^^ Should be answer

Comment: @Eric: I notices that now an answer like that gets automatically flagged as 'trivial answer' and is moved to comments.

Comment: @Remus Hmm... "trivial" or not, that definitely looks like the answer.  It appears I have 25 million ghost records in that table.  Assuming I am too impatient for the ghost cleanup, would the best way to go be to copy what little is left to a new table, and drop the existing one?

Comment: You can do an `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments:

*See [SQL Server “empty table” is slow after deleting all (12 million) records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14619/708) – Remus Rusanu*

The answer to this question is: **Ghosted Records**, subsequently confirmed by the original poster. Posting here for completeness.